# How to fire a event when the user enters the character in Android Edit Text?

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my android project. I want to fire a event(Display a dialog) when user enters particular character (ex: when user enters "s") .I tried on text watcher but the dialog is showing two times

Please any one help me in this

Added the code

```
mText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (s.charAt(s.length() - 1) == 's') {

                dialog.show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: plz show relevant part of code

Comment: add textwatcher to your edit text and use `afterTextChanged` to watch about the character you need...and second thing never use `==` operator to check strings. Instead of that use `myString.equals("myCharacter");`

Comment: What do you mean by showing twice?

Comment: @ Hoan Nguyen Edited the question

Comment: @Krishna : have u tried it using setOnKeyListener ? bu capturing 'S' and 's' key?

Comment: Are there 2 dialogs at the same time or the dialog shows again after the first one finish.

Comment: @HoanNguyen Two dialogs are showing at the same time

Comment: It seem like onTextChanged being called twice, why don't you log to see if onTextChanged being called twice

Answer (score 0):

You can add a TextWatcher, Like this:

```
 yourTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
     @Override
     public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
     }

     @Override
     public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
     }

     @Override
     public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
      //handle the text changed
     }
 });
```